# SQLite3 LIKE query with UTF-8 encoding

Tags: php, sqlite, sql-like

for MySQL I'm using this and works very well with UTF-8.

```
SELECT * FROM cat.item_list WHERE CONVERT(item_name USING utf8) LIKE (:searchString)
```

I've tried same query with sqlite but it doesn't work. What should I do for UTF-8 SQLite3 search query? (with LIKE)

my current sqlite3 qry (which doesn't work with UTF-8 charsets):

```
SELECT * FROM item_list WHERE item_name LIKE '%$safeName%'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved like that:

```
    $tr_chars = array('ç','Ç','ı','İ','ğ','Ğ','ü','ö','Ş','ş','Ö','Ü'); 
    $safeName = str_replace($tr_chars, '_', $safeName);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

`$query = "SELECT * FROM item_list WHERE item_name LIKE '%" . $safeName . "%'";`