# Query SQLite3 database with SELECT and parameters like with INSERT

Tags: python, sql, pandas, sqlite

I have a SQLite3 database with 1 table and many columns. The columns are a mix of REAL, INTEGERS, and TEXT. Some of the text entries contain datetimes.

I would like to insert rows into the table without adding duplicates. The table has more columns than I am inserting data. To do this, I would like to first query the table for any rows that contain all of the data that I would like to insert. If the table does not contain a row with the matching set of parameters, then insert the row.

If the table has 2 rows currently and looks like this:

```
a, b, c, d 
2019-09-20 00:00:00, 1.1, 'DOG', nan 
2019-10-20 10:00:00, 2.2, 'CAT', -2000
```

Inserting a row is simple:

```
insert_vals = [datetime.datetime(2019, 9, 27, 0, 0), 123.4, 'DOG']
column_names = ['a', 'b', 'c']
strDBInsert = "INSERT INTO table_name ({}) VALUES ({})".format(column_names, strQuestions)
conn = sqlite3.connect('db_name.db')
c= conn.cursor()
c.execute(strDBquery, insert_vals)
conn.commit()
```

However, is it possible to query the database in a similar way like below?

```
strDBquery = "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE {} LIKE {}".format(column_names, insert_vals)
c.execute(strDBquery, insert_vals)
queryData = c.fetchall()
```

The error I get is

```
 sqlite3.OperationalError: near ",": syntax error
```

I would expect output:

```
print(queryData)
Output: [datetime.datetime(2019, 9, 27, 0, 0), 123.4, 'DOG', nan]
```

The other option I think that I will need to go with is:

```
c.execute("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE a == datetime.datetime(2019, 9, 27, 0, 0), AND b == 123.4 AND c == DOG")
```

For more context, I am using python with pandas to read in a csv with stock transactions and I want to update a database with the new transactions. I then want to fill in other information to that transactions table and use another table in the database to hold portfolio information. Maybe there is a much easier way to do most of these without the query and then insert option.

Some other questions that are similar:

[SQLite3 querying a database with '?' placeholders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42665551/sqlite3-querying-a-database-with-placeholders)

[SQLite3 LIKE query with UTF-8 encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41602892/sqlite3-like-query-with-utf-8-encoding)

Comment: Maybe another option is just to build a string with the column titles and the values like this `conditions  = " AND ".join("{0} == {1}".format(x,y) for x,y in zip(column_names,insert_vals))`

Comment: Last hint for now:  If you ever have a problem with a constructed SQL statement, the first step should ALWAYS been to inspect (i.e. print and view) the full SQL string.  That gets right to the heart of the problem rather than guess what various code might do.  The goal is to create properly formatted SQL, so why not look at it directly?  Look at the final value of `strDBquery` before executing it to see what it looks like.  These details should also be included in a question on Stack Overflow.  Edit the question to add such details.

Comment: The primary question is valid, but the brainstorming style is ... uh... not traditional on Stack Overflow.  If you have ideas (like the various options and other SO questions), then it is best to try them out first and ask a question if none of the possible solutions function as expected.  All of the options are so close to working, but just have small syntax problems or misunderstanding, so it feels like you're asking us to just fix your typos and syntax errors... often details that could be discovered yourself by reviewing and researching syntax, etc.

Answer (score 0):

First go to docs when questions of syntax and parameters come up.  Generally SO answers are not for full tutorials, but the question and examples have a number of syntax errors, so the following paragraphs explain some basic sqlite SQL concepts.  To continue writing such code and avoid so many problems, one should study SQL syntax.

String values [must be in quotes](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html), just like in any other programming language.  Something like `c == DOG` would be interpreted as DOG a database object or keyword, not a value.

The [LIKE operator](https://sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#like) is for matching strings to a pattern.  It is not necessarily good for equality comparison of general values.  It is also not an automagical operator for comparing values of any data type.  It supports single parameters, not list of parameters.  If you need to match multiple strings, then multiple LIKE statements must be included, one for each column and/or comparison.

There are no actual date or time [data types for sqlite](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html).  There are [functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) for working with dates, but they are for generating date values as string and/or numeric Julian representations.  The expected string formats are ISO-8601 formats, like `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS`.  There is a `datetime()` function, but it does not accept the parameters as guessed in the question.  There also is *no referencing the host language functions* from SQL, so something like `datetime.datetime()` does not work.

Be careful of stray commas.

---

The overall pattern in this guess will be closest to a good solution:

> c.execute("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE a == datetime.datetime(2019, 9, 27, 0, 0), AND b == 123.4 AND c == DOG")

A corrected version of that statement would look like the following.  The datetime comparison will be executed as a string comparison with column `a`, so this assumes that columns `a` was previously saved using the same formats.  If that is not true, any datetime values will need to be manipulated and compared differently.

```
c.execute("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE a == datetime('2019-09-27 00:00:00') AND b == 123.4 AND c == 'DOG'")
```

The statement can certainly be generated from lists like `column_names` and `insert_vals`, but since the data types vary, it will not be a simple, uniform delimiter as the other guesses tried.  You'll need some form of data-type condition for preparing comparison expressions for each column.